# Set default value to filter

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am doing a React Dashboard using the React-Admin framework, and I would like to set on this :

```
<BooleanInput source="existe" alwaysOn />
```

I tried things like :

```
<BooleanInput source="existe" defaultValue={true} alwaysOn />
```

But it doesn't work at all, can someone help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I was just a bit stupid I think, I just have to set in my `<List>` component the property :

```
filterDefaultValues={{ existe: true }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your filter should look like:

```
const YourFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <BooleanInput source="existe" alwaysOn />
    </Filter>
);
```

And your `<List>` props should look like:

```
<List {...props} filters={<YourFilter />} filterDefaultValues={{ existe: true }}>
```